# Sending emails through python

Tags: python, email, hosting

I wish to setup a subscribe form. The user will fill his/her email address and on submit an email should be sent to the provided email address for verification. The verification email will have a link on which the user can click to verify the email address.

This form will be in a website which I plan to host at [Bluehost](https://www.bluehost.in/).

I read this [tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/send-emails-using-code-4fcea9df63f/) about how it can be done in Python. Following is a snippet from the tutorial

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP(host='your_host_address_here', port=your_port_here)
s.starttls()
s.login(MY_ADDRESS, PASSWORD)
```

My question is will I able to make this work on Bluehost ?,
My understanding is that host and port can be obtained as described
in this [link](https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/email-application-setup).

Also,is there any third-party service that allows me create such subscribe form as described above?

Answer (score 1):

While this could technically work, I highly recommend using a third-party service to send the actual emails. These days, the chance of your email getting delivered if it's being sent from a random Bluehost server is quite low due to its low "email sender reputation".

Snippet from [this link](https://www.sparkpost.com/resources/email-explained/email-sender-reputation/) explaining it:

> An email sender reputation is a score that an Internet Service Provider (ISP) assigns to an organization that sends email. It’s a crucial component of your email deliverability. The higher the score, the more likely an ISP will deliver emails to the inboxes of recipients on their network. If the score falls below a certain threshold, the ISP may send messages to recipients’ spam folders or even reject them outright.

Some email sending services include SendGrid or Amazon SES.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your website is static, then please go for third party service beacuse it will be difficult for you to handle the backend and integration part. So, look for some third party applications to do it for you for example [SendPulse](https://sendpulse.com/)
2. If your website is dynamic, i.e if its having some backend server part as well, then this email sending part can be done easily depending upon which language you are using at backend. Most languages has support for sending emails.